# Air Datepicker - dynamic minimum and maximum dates for highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

To select a date range, I use the [Air Datepicker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/index.html) plugin.

To connect the plugin, I use CDN:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/datepicker.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/air-datepicker/2.2.3/js/i18n/datepicker.en.min.js"></script>
```

Plugin Initialization:

```
var block = document.querySelector("#block");
    document.querySelector("#datepicker").addEventListener("focus", function() {
        block.style.display = "none";
    }, false);
    document.querySelector("#datepicker").addEventListener("blur", function() {
        block.style.display = "block";
    }, false);


    var maxdate = new Date(); //get current date
    maxdate.setDate(maxdate.getDate() + 14); //add 14 days
    function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/');
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
    }

    function datediff(first, second) {
    return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24));
    }

    $(function() {
        var myDatepicker =  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            language: 'en',
            range:true,
            autoClose: 'true',
            clearButton: 'true',                
            minDate: new Date(),
            maxDate: maxdate,
            multipleDatesSeparator : ' - ',
            onSelect: function onSelect(selectedDates) {
            console.log(selectedDates);
                if(selectedDates !== undefined && selectedDates != '' && selectedDates.indexOf('-') > -1){
                var mdy = selectedDates.split('-');
                $("#arr_date").val(mdy[0]);
                $("#dep_date").val(mdy[1]);                 
                $("#num_nights").val(datediff(parseDate(mdy[0]), parseDate(mdy[1])));
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Select..." class="rental-input" />
<!--Start Date <input type="text" id="arr_date"><br />
End Date <input type="text" id="dep_date"><br />-->
<div id="block">You have chosen: <input type="text" id="num_nights" class="rental-total" readonly />days rental</div>
```

How to make the following functionality? The user clicks on the first date, for example, April 1.

He is shown only 14 days, which he can choose, until April 14.

Either the user clicks on April 15, he also shows only 14 days, which can be selected, until April 29.

And so when you click on any first date.
In both cases, this is minDate: 0, and maxDate: 14,

I ask for your help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change a piece of your code.

```
onSelect: function onSelect(selectedDates) {
    console.log(selectedDates);
    if(selectedDates !== undefined && selectedDates.indexOf('-') <= -1 && selectedDates != ''){
        var dayst = selectedDates.split('.');
        dayst[0] = +dayst[0] + 14;
        var year = +dayst[2];
        var month = +dayst[1] - 1;
        var day = +dayst[0];
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            maxDate: new Date(year, month, day)
        });
    }
    else if(selectedDates !== undefined && selectedDates != '' && selectedDates.indexOf('-') > -1){
        var mdy = selectedDates.split('-');
        var dist = mdy[0].split('.');
        dist[0] = +dist[0] + 14;
        var year = +dist[2];
        var month = +dist[1] - 1;
        var day = +dist[0];
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        maxDate: new Date(year, month, day)
        });
    }
    else if(selectedDates !== undefined || selectedDates != ''){
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
            maxDate: ''
        });
    }
  }
})
});
```